# Wine using 200% CPU to run Might and Magic 6: Mandate of Heaven

Tags: wine, might-and-magic-6-mandate-of-heaven

I've installed MM6 using [this guide](https://www.gamersonlinux.com/forum/threads/might-and-magic-6-guide.491/), with the only differences that I'm using a virtual desktop size of 2400x1800 and recent versions of everything:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- PlayOnLinux 4.3.4
- Wine 5.0
- [GrayFace MM6 Patch v2.4](https://grayface.github.io/mm/#GrayFace-MM6-Patch)

The game works fine, but uses 200% CPU even when on the intro screen. Why would it use such a huge amount of CPU, and are there any simple ways to improve the situation?

A Wine debug session showed nothing obvious, but then I'm not an expert.

Comment: I am strictly windows user, but high CPU indicates unnecessary work, e.g. rendering too many frames per second. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/6ifz0j/reduce_cpu_usage_of_a_wine_application/) guy suggest to use vsync (check framerate first).